# Call to a member function getImage() on null

Tags: php, html, yii2

Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка

```html
                <?php
                    $mainImg = $product->getImage();
                ?>  


                <div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">
                    <?php if( !empty($hits) ): ?>
                    <div class="features_items"><!--features_items-->
                        <h2 class="title text-center">Хиты продаж</h2>
                        <?php foreach ($hits as $hit): ?>
                        
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                                <div class="single-products">
                                    <div class="productinfo text-center">

                                        <?php $mainImg = $product->getImage(); ?>
                                        <?= Html::img($mainImg->getUrl(), ['alt' => $product->name])?>

                                        <?= Html::img("@web/images/products/{$hit->img}", ['alt' => $hit->name]) ?>
                                        <h2><?= $hit->price?> руб</h2>
                                        <p><a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to(['product/view', 'id' => $hit->id]) ?>"><?= $hit->name?></a></p>
                                        <a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to(['cart/add', 'id' => $hit->id]) ?>" data-id="<?= $hit->id?>" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>В корзину</a>
                                    </div>

                                    <?php if($hit->new): ?>
                                        <?= Html::img("@web/images/home/new.png", ['alt' => 'Новинка', 'class' => 'new']) ?>
                                    <?php endif;?>

                                    <?php if($hit->sale): ?>
                                        <?= Html::img("@web/images/home/sale.png", ['alt' => 'Распродажа', 'class' => 'new']) ?>
                                    <?php endif;?>

                                </div>
                                <!-- <img src="images/home/new.png" class="new" alt="" /> -->
                                <!-- <img src="images/home/sale.png" class="new" alt="" /> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php endforeach;?>
                        
                    </div><!--features_items-->
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Ошибку славливаю здесь:

```
<?php $mainImg = $product->getImage();?>
```

Контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\Category;
use app\models\Product;
use Yii;

class ProductController extends AppController{

public function actionView($id){
    $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
    $product = Product::findOne($id);
    if(empty($product))
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'Данного товара не существует');

    // $product = Product::find()->with('category')->where(['id' = $id])->limit(1)->one();
    $hits = Product::find()->where(['hit' => '1'])->limit(6)->all();
    $this->setMeta('ASV-PAGE | ' . $product->name, $product->keywords, $product->description);
    return $this->render('view', compact('product', 'hits'));
}
```

}

Модель:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Product extends ActiveRecord{

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'image' => [
            'class' => 'rico\yii2images\behaviors\ImageBehave',
        ]
    ];
}

public static function tableName(){
    return 'product';
}

public function getCategory() {
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
}
```

}

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82716/discussion-on-question-by---call-to-a-member-function-getimage-o).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите выводить картинки всех товаров в actionIndex() - тогда в нем сделайте

```
$products = Product::find()->all(); 
return $this->render('index', compact('products', 'hits'));
```

И в самом представлении делаете

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
    <?= $product->getImage() ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Либо же, если это вывод одиночного товара - тогда уберите из вида **"views\category\index.php"** попытку вывода картинки, и перенесите вывод в файл, который рендерится в **actionView()**

Comment: не получается, можете пожалуйста сразу в код мой подставить, может я как-то не так понял и не так подставил

Comment: Вы хотите вывести эту картинку при просмотре карточки товара? тоесть только одна картинка?

Comment: есть главная, на ней есть как бы блок и в нем расположены хиты продаж, и вот в нем хочу вывести на товаре фото карточки

Comment: т.е. не все товары а только по разделу хиты

Comment: А, если хиты.
Тогда делаете вывод - $hit->getImage() в цикле. Не нужно вам просить картинку через $product которого нет. $hit  - экземпляр класса Product

Comment: можно в скайпе созвониться, а то у меня ошибка за ошибкой, так я вам весь код через экран покажу, может я что-то не так сделал )

Comment: Я на работе ) могу в личке / скайпе через переписку подсказать

Comment: вк есть, там хоть скрины смогу скинуть и там удобнее

Comment: https://vk.com/im?peers=346190194&sel=393803404